# Why is The Dark Knight Rises set after 8 years of The Dark Knight?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy

The Dark Knight Rises is set 8 years after the day Harvey Dent was killed.

Why did it take so long for Bane to plot an attack against Batman?

Comment: Asked and answered on Movies:SE - [What is the reason for setting the movie storyline 8 years apart?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/a/9121/7812)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess I'll just copy paste [Oliver C.'s answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/9121/30785).

> [**Christopher Nolan's answer**](http://www.comicbookmovie.com/fansites/GraphicCity/news/?a=64299) to the 8 year gap is:
>
> > ***It's partly about a physical and emotional toll and it's partly about being true to the end of [The Dark Knight].***
> >
> > *What you have at the end of 'The Dark Knight' is an ending that hangs very much on substantial sacrifice to achieve a certain end and for that to have meaning, it has to work in some sense, it has to have been successful. And **I didn't want to just abandon that and pick up a new story with a whole new set of ideas.***
> >
> > *So for me, that lead to the 8 year gap, it lead to the idea of Bruce Wayne, shut away in self-imposed exile because he's hung up his cape and cowl. He's living in a world, at least superficially, that doesn't need Batman but he hasn't moved on, he hasn't moved on as Alfred points out, he hasn't moved on emotionally or in a practical sense.*
>
> He reiterates this in [**another interview**](http://blastr.com/2011/12/chris-nolan-explains-that.php):
>
> > *... I think what we're saying is that **for Batman and Commissioner Gordon, there's a big sacrifice, a big compromise, at the end of the 'The Dark Knight'**, and for that to mean something, that sacrifice has to work, and Gotham has to get better in a sense. They have to achieve something for the ending of that film—and the feeling at the end of that film—to have validity.*
> >
> > ***Their sacrifice has to have meaning, and it takes time to establish that and to show that, and that's the primary reason we did that.***
> >
> > *It's a time period that is not so far ahead that we would have to do crazy makeup or anything—which I think would be distracting...*
>
> The last sentence sounds like he had thought about an even bigger gap, but decided against it because he wanted to avoid *'old people make-up'*.

Comment: It might have been OK if you searched this and found the other answer. But just copying the answer from the link provided by Richard seems questionable.

Comment: Could always turn this into a wiki so that votes don't affect reputation, although I'm okay with this.